# web based wysiwyg mail editor component

Tags: web, components, html-email, wysiwyg

I'm working on a web based application that needs to send email. I want my users to be able to create html templates with an easy editor. I don't want to build this component myself. Are there any components available that can do this which I can integrate in my application?

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of both free and licenced components out there. My favorite is TinyMCE.

https://www.tinymce.com/

A simple Google search will give you heaps of other choices.

I also used this one in my latest project, and it is also great:

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor

Comment: Does TinyMCE also work for Email templates? I know email has more limitations compared to normal html pages.

Comment: I have been using the Froala editor to create e-mails. On the version that I have I am stripping away the html codes/tags that can make problems in e-mails.